# How to create a new SQL Server(TSQL) database everyday with time stamp in it's name

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to create a script which say at everyday 09:00 am creates a new database and the name has a time stamp.

I have some CSV files which change everyday and I am loading them into a database called sales_TIMESTAMP. I am currently doing this manually. I want to create a code which runs everyday at a specific time and creates and populates the database. Say for today, it should create a database called sales_20160411

Any directions on how to approach this?

I am using microsoft SQL server express 2012

Comment: This is a whole new level. I've heard about [table per date](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm) but DB per date :)

Comment: You can do this by creating a script that sends SQL to the database that creates a database with the timestamp in its name. Also, this seems like a really bad idea to create new databases/tables/fields every time new data comes in.

Comment: @lad2025  FWIW, this is supposed to be a temporary thing for testing.

Comment: Set a job that will execute at 9.00 every day, write DDL queries (probably dynamic SQL will be needed to handle date in name) and yes this is completely possible.

Comment: Learn programming? This is extremely primitive string manipulation - replace a placeholder in a prepared SQL statement with the date.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - I wouldn't do it this way, as others have said.

Secondly - if you really have to, sqlcmd and bulk insert would seem to be your friends here. Running a SQL command from the task scheduler with sqlcmd isn't too tricky, so you can set that to run something like

```
EXEC ('CREATE DATABASE sales_ ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, SYSUTCDATETIME(), 112));
```

to create your database, then run a command to open and bulk load your CSV.